# Final field is mutable. What is my problem?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jackson, mybatis

I'm using mybatis and jackson-databind

And I tried to calculate some values in constructor of result type dto

Unfortunately, getter returns original values, not calculated values

I also tried to using @JsonCreator, @JsonProperty, etc...

But getter had return original value

Interestingly, When parameter names of constructor was changed(or sql alias), getter returned calculated value

I guess jackson or mybatis overrides something(or java reflection problem?)

How can I solve this problem without change some names?

This is my query

```
    <select id="getVoteResult" resultType="VoteResultDto">
        SELECT SUM(good) AS voteCountOfGood
             , SUM(bad) AS voteCountOfBad
        FROM some.recommend_inf
        WHERE id = #{id};
    </select>
```

and result dto

```
public final class VoteResultDto {
    private final int voteCountOfGood;
    private final int voteCountOfBad;

    public VoteResultDto(float voteCountOfGood, float voteCountOfBad) {
        System.out.println("float voteCountOfGood: " + voteCountOfGood);
        System.out.println("float voteCountOfBad: " + voteCountOfBad);
        if (voteCountOfGood > 0 || voteCountOfBad > 0) {
            this.voteCountOfGood = Math.round(voteCountOfGood / (voteCountOfGood + voteCountOfBad) * 100);
            this.voteCountOfBad = 100 - this.voteCountOfGood;
        } else {
            this.voteCountOfGood = this.voteCountOfBad = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("this.voteCountOfGood: " + this.voteCountOfGood);
        System.out.println("this.voteCountOfBad: " + this.voteCountOfBad);
    }

    public int getVoteCountOfGood() {
        return voteCountOfGood;
    }

    public int getVoteCountOfBad() {
        return voteCountOfBad;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "toString(): {voteCountOfGood: " + voteCountOfGood + ", voteCountOfBad: " + voteCountOfBad + '}';
    }
}
```

and log

```
float voteCountOfGood: 8.0
float voteCountOfBad: 4.0
this.voteCountOfGood: 67
this.voteCountOfBad: 33
toString(): {voteCountOfGood: 8, voteCountOfBad: 4}
```

Comment: It's a [know issue](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/2207) in constructor auto-mapping. You already found a workaround (i.e. using different column label in the result set). Another workaround is to define and use a result map with `<constructor />`.